# how to tell an infinite loop to end once one number repeats twice in a row (in python 3.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x

The title says it all. I have an infinite loop of randomly generated numbers from one to six that I need to end when 6 occurs twice in a row.

Comment: Keep the last number and if it and the current number are both `6`, end the loop. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am just new to programming in general so i still am unsure of the functions and commands necessary to tell my loop to finish once the number 6 occurs twice in a row.

Comment: We are nnot here to make your homework ;) Please think twice by yourself before asking us to solve your problems. If you do it, you should have try some stuff, please show it to us. Finally, read this before posting : [ask] ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a working example. With comments in the code so you can better understand each step.

```
# import required to use randint
import random

# holds the last number to be randomly generated
previous_number = None
while True: # infinite loop
    # generates a random number between 1 and 6
    num = random.randint(1, 6)
    # check if the last number was 6 and current number is 6
    if previous_number == 6 and num == 6:
        # if the above is true then break out the loop
        break
    # store the latest number and start the loop again
    previous_number = num
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help, I know this seems like I am outsourcing my work but I just don't know any of the terminology for functions etc., so thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

just `break` when the appropriate condition is met.
`break` leaves the loop instantly.

```
while True:
   # ...
   if last_val == val == 6:
      break
   last_val=val # save val for next iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    y = 0
    while 1:
        # --> "random Generator" rNumber
        if rNumber == 6:
            y +=1
        else: 
            y = 0

        if y == 2:
            break
```

Comment: no when y is incremented once and the next Loop any other number occurs it falls back to Zero only after 2 times 6 in a row it breaks the iinfinite loop

Comment: Hm, this seems really convoluted as a solution.

Comment: well we could do a Little refactoring and just say while y != 2 but my Intention was to make the solution very straightforward and simple to follow