# Concise way of stopping iteration when sentinel occurs twice in a row

Tags: python, iterator, generator, python-itertools, generator-expression

I'm looking for a way to generate an iterator that takes an iterable and just passes through the values until a sentinel value appears twice in direct succession. Similar to `iter(a.__next__, sentinel)` only that sentinel must occur twice.

The following rather uninspired code does the trick, but surely there must be a less verbose solution?

So to put it in a concrete question:

Is there a way to avoid the fully-fledged generator and achieve the same using perhaps `itertools` or a generator expression?

```
>>> def repeat_offenders(a, sentinel):
...    ia = iter(a)
...    for x in ia:
...       if x==sentinel:
...          try:
...             y = next(ia)
...          except StopIteration:
...             yield x
...             raise
...          if y==sentinel:
...             raise StopIteration
...          yield x
...          yield y
...       else:
...          yield x
```

Here are two examples:

```
>>> ''.join(repeat_offenders('ABCABCAABBCC', 'B'))
'ABCABCAA'
>>> ''.join(repeat_offenders('ABABAB', 'B'))
'ABABAB'
```

Note [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26489449/7207392) is similar but is lacking the generator angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `repeat_offenders` in terms of `iwindow`, a sliding window recipe (which can work on any iterable, not just sequences), and the usual `iter(callable, sentinel)` idiom:

```
import itertools as IT

def iwindow(iterable, n=2):
    """
    Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable.
    s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ..., (sk, None, ..., None)
    """
    iterables = IT.tee(iterable, n)
    iterables = (IT.islice(it, pos, None) for pos, it in enumerate(iterables))
    yield from IT.zip_longest(*iterables)

def repeat_offenders(iterable, sentinel, repeat=2):
    return (item[0] for item in iter(iwindow(iterable, repeat).__next__, 
                                     (sentinel,)*repeat))

print(''.join(repeat_offenders('ABCABCAABBCC', 'B', 2)))
# ABCABCAA

print(''.join(repeat_offenders('ABABAB', 'B', 2)))
# ABABAB
```

---

`iwindow` is a generalization of the [`pairwise` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#recipes) shown in the itertools docs. By writing `repeat_offenders` in terms of `iwindow`, we can generalize the concept to stopping after `n` repeats practically for free.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It is actually a bit slower than my humble generator (I suspect `tee` is to blame) but the easy generalization to more than two repeats is a nice bonus. And as you say `iwindow` is a useful thing to know.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps, but I believe your code can be written more succinctly as below:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def repeat_offenders_jp(a, s):
    for i, j in zip_longest(a, a[1:]):
        if i == j and i == s:
            break
        else:
            yield i

''.join(repeat_offenders_jp('ABCABCAABBCC', 'B'))  # 'ABCABCAA'
''.join(repeat_offenders_jp('ABABAB', 'B'))        # 'ABABAB'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here with `zip_longest` as @jp_data_analysis proposed but as "one-liner" and with `takewhile`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, takewhile

sentinel = 'B'
string = 'ABCABCAABBCC'
"".join(t[0] for t
        in takewhile(lambda t: t[0] != sentinel or t[0] != t[1], 
        zip_longest(string, string[1:])))
# 'ABCABCAA'

string = 'ABABAB'
"".join(t[0] for t
        in takewhile(lambda t: t[0] != sentinel or t[0] != t[1], 
        zip_longest(string, string[1:])))
# 'ABABAB'
```

Comment: Darkonaut, @jp_data_analysis, Maybe I didn't make it clear enough (well, I do say _iterable_ in the question) but I'm looking for something iterator-proof meaning that direct indexing, zipping with oneself etc. are not available. `strings` are only used for illustration.

Comment: @Paul Panzer strings _are_ iterables. Else you couldn't iterate over them. I think you wanted to ask about an iterator that takes in an iterator then?

Comment: Yes strings are iterables, but iterables are not necessarily strings. If something works for a string that doesn't mean it works for iterables in general. For example there are iterables - like file objects - which do not have a `__getitem__` method.

Comment: Where's the point in providing an example we can't work with? We must have assumed that _that's_ the kind of iterable you are working with. I'd suggest you make a new question with an appropriate example.

Comment: Every example will have features not representative of the concept the example exemplifies. It's a matter of common sense not to rely on those.